# MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json - android

Tags: java, android, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I'm using Jersey 2.17 & android to consume a web api made with Jersey.

I get the error

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json, type=class [Lcom.entities.Goal;, genericType=class [Lcom.entities.Goal;
```

I'm getting the error at

```
 public static Goal[] getGoals(String path){
        WebTarget webResource = getClient().target(ROOT + path);
        Invocation.Builder builder = webResource.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
        return builder.get(Goal[].class); // this line gives error
    }
```

I imported the library with

```
 compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.17'
```

I've tried adding some json libraries, but most of them would give me build errors like multiple dex , etc.

If I choose String.class it will work, and I will get a valid String.
And also the Goal class has an empty constructor.

Comment: Have you tried [Jersey documentation, chapter 9](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html) where it is explained how to add support for JSON and other media types?

Comment: I've tried with some of them, and I'm getting gradle build errors..they are not made for android I guess

Answer (score 2):

Erhannis comment is correct and worked for me.

You have to register the `JacksonJsonProvider` with your `ClientConfig` when creating your `Client`:

```
ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig(JacksonJsonProvider.class))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just got the same problem today.
You should add below dependency to your classpath:

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
       <version>2.23.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Problem is that Jersey client need a messageprovider to convert the response json to Java object. And we have added json-jackson provider.

Comment: If you've already done that, try `clientConfig.register(JacksonJsonProvider.class);`